# Distance calculation with square root on end result gives different result

Tags: java, math, processing

I can't wrap my head around this.
Why is the part where I square such significant smaller?
I know if I use `l += l` then I get the correct amount but it should not be that way I believe.

If we look at processings dist method:

```
  static public final float dist(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2) {
    return sqrt(sq(x2-x1) + sq(y2-y1));
  }
```

Then square root is used on the inner product. In my code I do this with the final result.

```
void setup() {
  
  // normal way, which gives correct result:
  float l = 0;

  l += dist(96.5, 89.0, 420.0, 97.5);
  l += dist(420.0, 97.5, 412.5, 409.5);
  l += dist(412.5, 409.5, 89.0, 420.0);
  l += dist(89.0, 420.0, 96.5, 89.0);

  println(l); // ok
  println(sqrt(sq(l))); // ok
  
  l = 0;
 
  l += distSQ(96.5, 89.0, 420.0, 97.5);
  l += distSQ(420.0, 97.5, 412.5, 409.5);
  l += distSQ(412.5, 409.5, 89.0, 420.0);
  l += distSQ(89.0, 420.0, 96.5, 89.0);
      
  l = sqrt(l);
  
  println("why is this one smaller? "+l); // should be twice as big
  
}

static protected final float distSQ(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2) {
  return sq(x2-x1) + sq(y2-y1);
}
```

edit:

output is:

> 1290.457
>
> 1290.457
>
> why is this one smaller? 645.3716

Comment: It would really help if you'd show us the output you're getting and the output you're expecting. Where does "should be twice as big" come from? It's really not at all clear what result you're expecting, but summing the squares of distances is unlikely to be useful.

Comment: What is sqrt and sq? Are those your own methods?

Comment: could you show the output please so as to undersstand

Comment: `println(sqrt(sq(l))); // ok` and `l = sqrt(l);`. `sqrt(sq(l))` should result in `l` whereas `sqrt(l)` results in the square root of `l`, that is why it is smaller.

Comment: @JonSkeet edited post, added output

Comment: @clankill3r your sqrt() function seems to be dividing by 2 which must mean your sq() function is multiplying by 2.

Comment: @JonnyHenly yeah but I use a distance method 4 times where it does not give give the square root product. And then I do that on the end result.

Comment: @clankill3r there is no difference between `println(l);` and `println(sqrt(sq(l)));` however there is a difference between `println(l);` and `println(sqrt(l));`

Comment: It's still not clear why you *expect* the results to be the same. Generally, the square root of a sum of squares *isn't* the sum of the original values. `sqrt(x*x + y*y) != x + y`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
l += dist(96.5, 89.0, 420.0, 97.5);
l += dist(420.0, 97.5, 412.5, 409.5);
...
```

Is like

```
l = sqrt(a^2+b^2) + sqrt(c^2+d^2)...
```

But

```
l += distSQ(96.5, 89.0, 420.0, 97.5);
l += distSQ(420.0, 97.5, 412.5, 409.5);
l = sqrt(l);
```

Is like

```
l = sqrt(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2...)
```

They are not equivalent. Here's an example `sqrt(9)+sqrt(4)=5` but `sqrt(9+4)=3.6`

Answer (score 1):

If you think that `(a + b + c + d) * (a + b + c + d)`  is equal to `aa + bb + cc + dd` then we should publish jointly!

So,

```
 l += distSQ(96.5, 89.0, 420.0, 97.5);
 l += distSQ(420.0, 97.5, 412.5, 409.5);
 l += distSQ(412.5, 409.5, 89.0, 420.0);
 l += distSQ(89.0, 420.0, 96.5, 89.0);
 l = sqrt(l);
```

is a very different value to

```
  l += dist(96.5, 89.0, 420.0, 97.5);
  l += dist(420.0, 97.5, 412.5, 409.5);
  l += dist(412.5, 409.5, 89.0, 420.0);
  l += dist(89.0, 420.0, 96.5, 89.0);
```

Comment: what line are you referring to? :) I don't understand your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Just put the brackets over the return statement at distSQ

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth stating that what you expect from the square root function `sqrt` only happens for linear functions*.

A function `f`, that takes a real and returns a real, verifies `f(a+b) = f(a)+f(b)` for all a and b (thus what you expect) is necessarily defined by a constant `c` such that `f(x)=c*x`.

You can see that the reciprocal is true as well and easy to see : `c*a+c*b = c*(a+b)`

In that case, plotting `f` would result in a straight line that goes through the origin (the point (0,0)), which you know is not the case for the square root : http://fooplot.com/plot/rojyepxjog

---

* This is true on the rationals, you have to add a few pathological cases on the real numbers, but nothing that would affect your daily life.